# How to call `beginRequest` of Call Directory Extension?

Tags: ios, swift, callkit

I have to test about Call Blocking & Identification. So I followed the steps below.

(1) Create a Call Directory Extension in my project from [File] > [New] > [Target].

(2) Add a logging in Call Directory Extension to test.

```
class CallDirectoryHandler: CXCallDirectoryProvider {
  override func beginRequest(with context: CXCallDirectoryExtensionContext) {
    print("test")
  }
}
```

(3) Call reload function of CallKit on my project.

```
CXCallDirectoryManager.sharedInstance.reloadExtension(withIdentifier: "EXTENSION_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER", completionHandler: { (error) in
  if let error = error {
    print(error.localizedDescription)

  } else {
    print("success")
  }
})
```

(4) Check my app is enabled in `Settings > Phone > Call blocking & identification`.

And `success` of 3 is printed, but `test` of 2 isn't printed.

Is there anything I should check?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it is being called correctly as you can check the response on your app target sandbox.

The only way I know to get access to the logs in this case is by going in the **Devices window of Xcode** and looking at the `device console`, you should be able to see logs like this:

`com.apple.CallKit.CallDirectory: ...`

You might also try to debug it by putting directly a breakpoint in this line:

> print("test")

Check also tutorials on finding out if you have any issue in the setup between your extension and your app sandboxes, there is a good one here: https://pusher.com/tutorials/callkit-ios-part-1